# How can I copy a larger number of cells into a smaller number of cells that are already feeding a graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, database, spreadsheet, selection

I have two 10-cell columns that currently feed a graph (one for the x-axis, the other for the y-axis). I have now doubled the discretization of my dataset, so instead of the original 10 data points, I now have 20.

Can I easily copy this new 20x2 matrix into the section of the spreadsheet currently occupied by the 10x2 matrix that presently feeds my graph (so I don't have to manually reselect the data for my graph)?

I obviously know how to reselect data for a graph manually. I have to perform this operation **hundreds of times**, though. That's why I'm asking about the hopeful existence of a more effective way to do what I need to do...

Comment: If you have changed data sets for hundreds of graphs you have to think about the case of a new data change. An answer depends very much on the way you organise your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

- Your data set is in A1:B10 and the chart uses A1:B10 [image]
- insert 10 rows between row 1 and row 10
- the chart now uses A1:B20 [image]
- paste the new, 20-row data into A1:B20 [image]

Comment: This did resolve my issue, @teylyn! Thanks for helping! 